# DataGridView - make custom cell control visible on getting focus

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am implementing custom NumericUpDownColumn to a DataGridView in c#.

It's working great, except for the fact that the numeric control get visible only after triple-clicking the custom cell.

I want it to be visible right when the cell get into focus. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy...  I was able to solve this by setting the EditMode property of the DataGridView to EditOnEnter.